# Count consecutive occurences of an element in string

Tags: r

Yesterday I have asked similar question
[Count each next occurence of string in substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280116/count-each-next-occurence-of-string-in-substring)
now I'm struggling with another one:

```
apple.a > banana.b > banana.b > carrot-c > banana.b > apple.a > carrot-c > banana.b > apple.a
```

What I want to achieve, is to check consecutive occurences, so the result would be

```
apple.a1 > banana.b1 > banana.b2 > carrot-c1 > banana.b1 > apple.a1 > carrot-c1 > banana.b1 > apple.a1
```

I have already tried several solutions:

[Count consecutive TRUE values within each block separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551492/count-consecutive-true-values-within-each-block-separately)

[Counting the number of occurrences of a value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310218/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-value-in-r)

[R: count consecutive occurrences of values in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998836/r-count-consecutive-occurrences-of-values-in-a-single-column)

to list few of them, but none seem to have worked for me and I couldn't achieve desired results. I tried to combine `strsplit` with `unlist`, `sequence`, `rle` and several other functions and wasn't able to overcome my problem.

To clear things up: data frame has several columns and sequence of words is stored in one of them.

Comment: `lapply(strsplit(s, " > "), function(x) paste0(x, data.table::rowid(rleid(x)), collapse = " > "))`

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I have been looking for, thank you!

Comment: I realized I used the `rowid(rleid(x))` in the post you looked at: [Count consecutive TRUE values within each block separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552636/1851712) ;)

Comment: Looks like you are... consistent in usage of functions ;-)

Comment: I am sorry, I deleted my previous comment as it was pointing at how dumb I am, got myself another coffee and sorted it out. It seems like a long way for me until I learn how to use R properly. 

toString both in my "main" code and sample snippets messed things up, I thought it just casts each value to string, my bad, thank you for clarification though.

Now it works really awesome and is going to provide me some really useful insights to my work, thank you!

Comment: No problem Marcin. You should not underestimate the wonders of an extra cup of coffee. Glad to hear that it work the way you wanted.

Comment: No, it works great and got me really ahead with my work. Thank you for your time and patience, your help was priceless for me, I mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the pieces together: here's a combination of [my comment on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280116/count-each-next-occurence-of-string-in-substring#comment93443137_53280414) and (parts of) my answer here: [Count consecutive TRUE values within each block separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552636/1851712). The convenience functions `rleid` and `rowid` from the `data.table` package are used.

Toy data with two strings of different length:

```
s <- c("a > a > b > b > b > a > b > b", "c > c > b > b > b > c > c")

library(data.table)
lapply(strsplit(s, " > "), function(x) paste0(x, rowid(rleid(x)), collapse = " > "))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a1 > a2 > b1 > b2 > b3 > a1 > b1 > b2"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "c1 > c2 > b1 > b2 > b3 > c1 > c2"
```